# Using NSFetchRequest how to get last X items and continue upward

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Im using `NSFetchRequest` in `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch data, sorted based on date

```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES];
```

As you can see it sorts the results based on timestamp and I can get ascending and descending results.

but what i want is, lets say if i have 1-100 rows.
In first query I want to have 95-100 results, then 90-100 , then 85-100 so on...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set [`fetchOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchOffset) and [`fetchLimit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchLimit) of your NSFetchRequest.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchOffset` and `fetchLimit` will help you to paginate your results, this is not my problem.

changing `NSSortDescriptor` to ascend or descend will show results like this
10-to-6 then in second iteration 10-to-1 Or  1-to-5 and in second iteration 1-to-10

what I wanted was, for instance, if i have rows 1-to-10 i wanted to show rows 6-to-10 in first iteration and 1-to-10 in second iteration in same order.

You can achieve this results by using NSPredicate

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp >=%@",[[NSDate date] dateBySubtractingDays:self.page]];
```